# How to use regular expression to find all numbers between special strings?

Tags: java, c++, regex

Given a string: **HelloWorld{12:777}ByeWorld{13:888}OkayWorld{14:999}**

My desired output are:

```
12
13
14
```

How to write a pattern (in C++ or Java) to find all numbers between string "**World{**" and "**:**"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use lookarounds or capturing group.

```
Pattern.compile("(?<=World\\{)[^:]*(?=:)");
```

or

```
Pattern.compile("\\bWorld\\{([^:]*):");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    char ch[100];

    scanf("%s", ch);
    char *token;
    token = strtok(ch, "{");
    token = strtok(NULL, ":");
    cout<< token << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The question is about C++, Regex and a more specific pattern. This C answer with solely C++ output and simplified search is just ugly :/